# Javascript display a list of nested lists

Tags: javascript

I have this list of nested list:

```
var align_map = [[[[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31], [32], [33], [34], [35], [36], [37], [38], [39], [40], [41], [42], [43], [44], [45], [46], [47], [48], [49], [50], [51], [52], [53], [54], [55], [56], [57], [58], [59], [60], [61], [62], [63], [64], [65], [66], [67], [68], [69], [70], [71], [72], [73], [74], [75], [76], [77], [78], [79], [80], [81], [82], [83], [84], [85], [86], [87], [88], [89], [90], [91], [92], [93], [94], [95], [96], [97], [98], [99], [100], [101], [102], [103], [104], [105], [106]], [[0], [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12], [13], [14], [15], [16], [17], [18], [19], [20], [21], [22], [23], [24], [25], [26], [27], [28], [29], [30], [31], [32], [33], [34], [35], [36], [37], [38], [39], [40], [41], [42], [43], [44], [45], [46], [47], [48], [49], [50], [51], [52], [53], [54], [55], [56], [57], [58], [59], [60], [61], [62], [63], [64], [65], [66], [67], [68], [69], [70], [71], [72], [73], [74], [75], [76], [77], [78], [79], [80], [81], [82], [83], [84], [85], [86], [87], [88], [89], [90], [91], [92], [93], [94], [95], [96], [97], [98], [99], [100], [101], [102], [103], [104], [105], [106], [107], [108]]]];
```

and I want to display it nicely to show the square brackets indicating each sub-list (not just using (.toSring())

Comment: Can you show an example of how you expect this to be displayed, as well as what you have tried so far?

Comment: I tried to use alert(align_map.toString()).. and I want it to be displayed with the brackets, not just putting all the elements togther separated by spaces

Comment: create a method and show it as you like?

Comment: @hmghaly How can you do what?  You still haven't shown an example.

Comment: It's unclear what you need, but I suspect something like `JSON.stringify(align_map)` might get you what you need.

Comment: thanks @Brad, I thought it is obvious and other people got it, thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) does exactly what you want in this case:

```
JSON.stringify(align_map);
```